# Auto-incremento no Excel, baseado no valor da linha

Tags: microsoft-excel

Tenho as seguintes células e colunas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Necessitava de criar um auto-incremento,  na coluna B, incrementando apenas quando o valor da coluna A for diferente, iniciando com "1". A coluna C mostra o resultado pretendido.

Tentei com diversos "SE" mas sem sucesso.

Agradeço a vossa ajuda.

Comment: Este é o StackOverflow em Português. Por favor, faça perguntas na língua portuguesa :)

Comment: Tem razão, é o hábito. Corrigido. Obrigado

Comment: Sem problemas. Boa sorte!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode alcançar isso com somente 3 funções SE.

Coloque a seguinte função na célular **B2**

```
=SE(A2=A1;SE(ÉNÚM(B1);B1;1);SE(ÉNÚM(B1);B1+1;1))
```

Explicação da lógica:

- O primeiro SE vai fazer a verificação se a célula que 1 casa a esquerda é igual a célula que está 1 casa a esquerda e 1 a cima (No caso de B2 a comparação seria feita em A2 e A1);
- Se verdadeiro, então entramos na segunda função SE, ela confere se a célula acima da função tem um valor numérico, se SIM, então o número é duplicado, caso não é colocado o número 1.
- Se falso, então entramos na terceira função SE, ela também irá conferir se a célula acima da função tem um valor numérico, se SIM, então o número é incrementado a 1, caso não é colocado o número 1.

Comment: {=ROUND(SUM(1/COUNTIF($A$2:$A$10;$A10:$A$10));0)}

Comment: Excelente! Funcionou em pleno. Muito obrigado pela fórmula e pela explicação.